# Efficiently Iterating Over A Large MongoDB Collection

Tags: java, mongodb, multithreading, parallel-processing, bloom-filter

I am writing a large data reader that created almost a fifty million documents inside of mongodb, and in counting (+2million a day). Basically in order to store data into mongodb, i need to first check if the record already exist. To do this, I use a combination of Redis and a bloom filter. Because the bloom filter is completely in memory, I need to load it every time the program is started, thus bringing me to my problem.

Currently I use an iterator (mongo cursor) to iterate through every single document stored inside the specific mongo collection. This is an example:

```
private final static MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase(Constants.MONGO_SCHEMA_NAME);
private final static MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection(Constants.MONGO_SITE_COLLECTION_NAME);

public void load(){
    MongoCursor cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        Document document = (Document)cursor.next();
        if(document != null){
            Filters.add(document.get(Constants.MONGO_ELEMENT_URL_FIELD_NAME).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Where add is a function invoked to add the url to both redis and the bloom filter. I use both redis and a bloom filter because a bloom filter is faster than redis and redis is faster than mongo. This guarantees I never have to search through mongo to see if a document already exist (which is significantly slower than redis from my understanding)

I was wondering if it is possible to "split" a collection temporarily or create multiple cursors to iterate through the collection via parallel processing to speed up the time it takes to load my filters (Redis and Bloom Filter). So instead of reading a collection from A -> Z, I would have ideally 26 cursors to read A->B and B->C and ... and M->N and ... and Y->Z all concurrently.

Thank you! :)

Comment: It would totally help to see a sample document with the fields denoted which are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Hi yes, my documents are very simple actually. They have a unique field for url and a second field for parsed text. That's about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not a suitable approach for this. There are two much better alternatives:

1: Instead of checking if record already exist or not create a unique index on the field/fields you do not want to duplicate

2: Create a index for which you checking against, it will extremely improve your query speed but inserts and updates will take bit more time.

Comment: @VincentTan To expand on this: If you have created a unique index over your set of fields, simply try to insert the data. If the record already exists, MongoDB will reject it with an according [DuplicateKeyException](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/DuplicateKeyException.html#DuplicateKeyException-org.bson.BsonDocument-com.mongodb.ServerAddress-com.mongodb.WriteConcernResult-). No need for a Bloom filter or Redis.

Comment: These are both good advices I didnt know mongo could do this! Thanks! But I would prefer to check using a bloom filter as I have a task queue that inserts parsed data. This operation can be expensive so I would want to cut the possibility of parsing the same data repeated times. Any more advice for faster / more efficient reading?

Comment: Firstly add unique index then, 
Simply add a try catch block to handle exceptions on task level or if you are using insertMany then set the ordered in options to true it will continue insertion even if some items in array are failed to be inserted.

For further performance improvement read about writeConcern in mongoDb